# Typescript node.js is possible to print keys from interface?

Tags: node.js, typescript

i'm using node.js with typescript and I have a question

I create a type from interfaces key, and my doubt its possible to print de key list?

```
interface IFooReal {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
}


type KnownKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;

type KnownKeysOfAnother = KnownKeys<IFooReal> 

console.log(KnownKeysOfAnother) <== How to print a keys of my interface??
```

I know the interface not exists in  runtime, but i think about TS Transformation plugin, for build time create a array of strings with the property name.

I created a web api rest, and I'd like to cast the  body from request to get an object with the properties only of the interface. Even though the request body has other properties.

```
documentRouter.post('/', async (req, res) => { 
  cont myObjet: IIFooReal = req.body

});
```

Comment: You don't – the interface no longer exists at runtime.

Comment: I understand, but i can write a transform plugin? to get keys from interfaces and create a array of string with names of property?

Comment: You don't need to write one, you can use https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys – but then you're drifting away from vanilla TypeScript, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

### It's not possible.

TypeScript transpiles into JavasScript at compile-time. On run-time you have only JavaScript.

There is a [Using type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), but that is not a solution at all.

Think in this way, if you need console.log TS types then you are doing something wrong. If you'd explain the philosophic reason of doing that maybe we could help you to figure out the other vector of thinking

Comment: I created a web api rest, and I'd like to cast the  body from request to get an object with the properties only of the interface. Even though the request body has other properties.

```
documentRouter.post('/', async (req, res) => { 
  cont myObjet: IIFooReal = req.body

});
```

Comment: @LucianoCastro So create a new object, this one having just what you need.

Comment: @LucianoCastro Imagine you don't have TS at that moment, how would you do it in vanilla JS? What is type of API? Can sort of `.type` property be added into req.body to determine which set of keys you can operate with?

Comment: @LucianoCastro Don't think that TS is something magical. It's just an additional layer under JS, it's not a separate language. It is a great tool to reduce amount of potential bugs before compile/transpile. Believe it or not some good pros every once in a while used `any` in their production code :) Yeah of course you should avoid that, but that's not something critical if you know what you are doing. Focus more on run-time checking when writing API, manage risks that could happen on runtime

Comment: @LucianoCastro I love TS. I use it all the time with Angular, React, NodeJS on prod, but my workflow does not allow me to stop because of I can't manage TS warning or errors. I just make something that works with less impact (event using `any` is a temporal solution) and put // TODO to come back later. If you are working on a feature, don't stop, do the rest for now. If you are practising a TS then you probably went out of the way a little bit. TS can't do it and has not supposed to.